# Spring data neo4j, I cant delete node by id

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using latest version of SDN.

I have repository with delete method

```
   @Override   
    @Query("MATCH (n:`User`) WHERE ID(n)={0} DELETE n")
    public void delete(Long id);
```

and method from Spring service which is pass id

```
  @Transactional
    public Long deleteUser(Long id) {
        User user = repository.findOne(id);
        if (user != null) {
          //  template.delete(user );
            repository.delete(user .getNodeId());
            log.info("deleted user with getNodeId  " + user .getNodeId());

        }
        return id;
}
```

Entity

```
@NodeEntity(useShortNames = true)
@TypeAlias("User")
public class User{

    @GraphId
    private Long nodeId;
    @Indexed(unique = false)
    @GraphProperty
    private String articleId;
```

So Id passed 100% and from db I get one entity and try to delete it by id
or with neo4j template, but it does not delete, why? i do not know, no any error

Comment: What is the "latest version?" 3.2.x or 3.3.x ?

Comment: Why don't you use template.delete(user) ?

Comment: What happens if you execute your query manually? Does it work then?

Comment: actually all working, just after delete I did not get updated graph list immediately.